# Slow API response --Angular

Tags: angular, api

I connected my one field of form which is fetching data from database of 3rd party database. Now I am facing performance issue because of delay of 3rd party site loading time. What can I do to improve the performance of my web application? Should I create a small service in the web app to load the User List from API and keep it in memory?

If that's a solution please guide me how can I do this?

Comment: if you're worried about the data loading for a long time on each page reload, you may simply cache it in the local storage in the browser and then just load from there first and fire API request after.

Comment: Is the cause a hugh response cntent? Does the API maybe offer pagination options?

Comment: Read this: [ask]